# Deleting rows from single Table using inner Join

Tags: mysql

I am having difficulties removing rows from my MySQL database.  I have two tables that I am Joining.  Joining may not be the best solutions and I am definitely open to suggestions. the tables are as follows

```
     Table a
```

part_number, cat_code,description

```
      Table b
```

part_number, cat_code,description

Table b is the correct table its contents has recently been updated. Table b only has a single product line.  Table a has All product Lines that the company currently and previously made.Table a has old data and part_numbers that are duplicated and associated with multiple cat_codes.

Properly the cat_codes should have a one to Many relationship with part_numbers.For Example part_number 123,456,and 789 can have a cat_code of 1A.The primary key of both tables are part_number+cat_code

When I run this select statement I get the output of the unique identifiers I need to remove from table a.

```
SELECT CONCAT(a.part_number,a.cat_code)
FROM
b
INNER JOIN
a 
WHERE
a.part_numer = b.part_number
AND a.cat_code != b.cat_code
```

But when I try to use that select statement in a DELETE FROM Statement it doesn't work.  Here is the broken statement.

```
DELETE FROM
a
WHERE
CONCAT(part_number,cat_code) IN (SELECT CONCAT(a.part_number,a.cat_code)
FROM
b
INNER JOIN
a 
WHERE
a.part_numer = b.part_number
AND a.cat_code != b.cat_code)
```

Any Help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: It gives no errors, only returns no rows affected.

Answer (score 0):

The `DELETE` command doesn't have an `IN` parameter, so you need parentheses around your subquery. Try:

```
DELETE FROM a 
WHERE (
    CONCAT(part_number,cat_code) 
    IN (SELECT CONCAT(a.part_number,a.cat_code) 
        FROM b INNER JOIN a WHERE a.part_numer = b.part_number 
          AND  a.cat_code != b.cat_code)
    )
```

For more information on `DELETE`, see the MySql [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/delete.html). In particular, for a single table the syntax is:

> ```
> DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE] FROM tbl_name
> [WHERE where_condition]
> [ORDER BY ...]
> [LIMIT row_count]
> ```

Comment: I will try this with the next table comparison and update.  What I did for a work around is create a single column table and then insert into table the results from my first Query.                                                               INSERT INTO key SELECT CONCAT(a.part_number,a.cat_code)
FROM
b
INNER JOIN
a 
WHERE
a.part_numer = b.part_number
AND a.cat_code != b.cat_code;                                                         Then I just made used the key table to compare against for the deletion.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do delete with a join- unless i'm missing something:

```
DELETE a
FROM a
INNER JOIN b
ON b.part_number = a.part_number
AND a.cat_code != b.cat_code
```

Comment: I have many more product lines to test against so I will also give your method a try.  It looks like your method is the most elegant.  Thank you for your input.  I will post back to this thread all my results.